# Paths of the generated pages with assemble

Tags: gruntjs, assemble, grunt-assemble

I am struggling with the [grunt-assemble](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble) grunt task configuration which looks like this:

```js
assemble: {
  options: {
    flatten: false,
    expand: true,

    assets: '',

    layout: 'default.hbs',
    layoutdir: 'templates/layouts',

    partials: ['templates/includes/*.hbs'],
    helpers: ['templates/helpers/*.js'],
    data: ['templates/data/*.{json,yml}']
  },

  dev: {
    src: 'templates/pages/**/*.hbs',
    dest: 'build/'
  }
```

The scaffolding of the project templates for assemble.io looks like:

```
templates
├── helpers
├── includes
│   ├── page-footer.hbs
│   ├── page-header.hbs
│   └── scripts.hbs
├── layouts
│   └── default.hbs
└── pages
    ├── en
    │   └── index.hbs
    ├── fr
    │   └── index.hbs
    └── index.hbs
```

My wish is go get something like:

```
build
├── en
│   └── index.html
├── fr
│   └── index.html
└── index.html
```

But instead I get something like:

```
build
└── templates
    └── pages
        ├── en
        │   └── index.html
        ├── fr
        │   └── index.html
        └── index.html
```

I did try a few (a lot actually) of combinations (with the `flatten` and `expand` as well as the `cwd` options) but I am stuck.

Using `flatten` has for consequence to make the `index.html` files to overwrite each others.

So I actually do the rendering into a *.tmp* directory and then move the files to the *build* directory.
I do not like that solution because then, the `page.assets` is still *broken* (its value would be `../../..`, for the root index.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**grunt-assemble**

*(Note that this information refers specifically to grunt-assemble 0.4.x, which is the grunt plugin for assemble but has a completely different API)*

@doowb almost has it right, try adding `expand: true` and `ext: '.html'` to the files config:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    flatten: false,
    expand: true,

    assets: '',

    layout: 'default.hbs',
    layoutdir: 'templates/layouts',

    partials: ['templates/includes/*.hbs'],
    helpers: ['templates/helpers/*.js'],
    data: ['templates/data/*.{json,yml}']
  },

  dev: {
    files: [
      {expand: true, cwd: 'templates/pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: 'build/', ext: '.html'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Also take a look at https://github.com/assemble/assemble-contrib-permalinks

**assemble 0.7.x**

Collections are first-class in assemble 0.7.0, as are plugins, so things like generating relative links, building pagination, and creating custom permalinks are much easier to do.

If you're using assemble 0.7.x and up, [assemble-permalinks](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-permalinks) is the plugin you'd want to use.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking at the right place, but it gets a bit confusing with the `files` object or other possible syntax.

Comment: How would this be done using node assemble @jonschlinkert @doowb?
Would it be something like... app.pages([path to pages], { [file config]} or is this just a grunt thing atm?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using the expanded `files` object for grunt targets with the `cwd` property?

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    flatten: false,
    expand: true,

    assets: '',

    layout: 'default.hbs',
    layoutdir: 'templates/layouts',

    partials: ['templates/includes/*.hbs'],
    helpers: ['templates/helpers/*.js'],
    data: ['templates/data/*.{json,yml}']
  },

  dev: {
    files: [
      { cwd: 'templates/pages/', src: '**/*.hbs', dest: 'build/' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually did.
got errors about files not found, looking like that


    Error: Unable to read "index.hbs" file (Error code: ENOENT).
    at Object.util.error (..../node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/util.js:57:39)
    at Object.file.read (..../node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/file.js:237:22)
    at buildPage (..../node_modules/assemble/tasks/assemble.js:289:78)
    at ..../node_modules/assemble/tasks/assemble.js:345:23