# How to omit a folder from the output file structure of a Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

Im running a grunt task to build an Assemble site.

My task is configured as follows:

```
    assemble: {

        options: {
            flatten: false,
            assets: '<%= config.dist %>',
            dist: '<%= config.dist %>',
            layout: 'default.hbs',
            layoutdir: 'templates/layouts/',
            partials: 'templates/partials/*.hbs',
        },

        pages: {
            files: { '<%= config.dist %>': ['pages/{,*/}*.hbs'] }
        }

    },
```

In my source files, I have a structure like this:

```
 pages
    cat1
    cat2
```

This is outputting something like:

```
  dist
      pages
         cat1
         cat2
```

How can I setup the task so that it won't include the /pages folder but still generate the subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jakerella is close but missing one piece, `ext`. It should be:

```
files: [
  {
    expand: true, 
    cwd: 'pages', 
    src: ['**/*.hbs'], 
    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/', 
    ext: '.html'
  }
]
```

Comment: Ack... I did forget that. :/

Answer (score 1):

So you want it to be just `dist->cat1` and `dist->cat2`? I think you'll need to tweak your `pages` target a bit, but I think you're looking for the `expand` and `cwd` options:

```
pages: {
    files: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'pages/',
        src: ['**/*.hbs'],
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
        ext: '.html'
    }
}
```

(This was partially yanked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158537/1985406).)

**EDIT** Added the `ext` option as well.